# How to Display text on canvas when clicked on a randomly moving bitmap image?

Tags: android

*The bitmap image(smiling) in my code moves randomly on screen. I want to display a message whenever user clicks on the randomly moving bitmap image.I tried using Ontouch() method but couldn't find a solution.*

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
Myclass ourView;
Bitmap smile;
TextView dis;
int x=0,y=0,a=0,b=0;


 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ourView=new Myclass(this);
    setContentView(ourView);



}

 public class Myclass extends View implements OnTouchListener{


        int changingX=0,changingY=0;
        Random crazy = new Random();
        Paint ourblue=new Paint();
        Paint Text=new Paint();
        Paint text=new Paint();


        public Myclass(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            smile=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.smiling);

        }



        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            ourblue.setARGB(220, 221, 243, 249);
            canvas.drawPaint(ourblue);
             a=crazy.nextInt(350);
             b=crazy.nextInt(550);
            canvas.drawBitmap(smile,a,b , null);


            if(x>(a-20)&&x<(a+20)&&y>(b-20)&&y<(b+20))
            {

                text.setARGB(220, 0, 0, 0);
                text.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
                text.setTextSize(50);
                canvas.drawText("Awesome", 100, 100, text);
            }



            for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
            {
            }
            invalidate();




        }

        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            x=(int) event.getX();
             y=(int) event.getY();
            return true;


        }

 }
```

}

Comment: Please edit your sourcecode to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep track of your Bitmap's rectangle as it moves randomly
2. Create a class-wide flag: `boolean displayText`
3. In your `onTouch` method, always check if the touch occurs inside your Bitmap's rectangle. If it does, then set `displayText = true` else set it to `false`
4. In your `onDraw` method, check if `displayText` is true, if so draw the text. If not, don't draw it.